# Сохранение файла в базе данных

Tags: python

Всем привет!

У меня есть такая таблица в БД:

```
CREATE TABLE "Reports_MCHS"
(  
  "Script" bytea,                      
  "Name" text,  
  "Specify_params" integer,  
 )  
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);  
ALTER TABLE "Reports_MCHS" OWNER TO postgres;
```

В поле "Script" хранятся текстовые файлы - скрипты на питоне. Пишу скрипт, который добавляет файлы(новые скрипты) в эту таблицу.

```
import sys  
import psycopg2

HOST    = 'localhost'  
DB_NAME = 'gar'  
DB_USER = 'postgres'  
DB_PASS = ''

""" Открываем файл и читаем его в строковую переменную """  
s=open('report_29.py','r').read()

"""обрамляем текст в кавычки"""  
s = "'" + s + "'"

""" Соединяемся с сервером БД """
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST,database=DB_NAME,user=DB_USER,password=DB_PASS)  
curs = conn.cursor()

"""Добавляем запись в таблицу БД"""  
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO "Reports_MCHS" VALUES (%s,'NewReport',4,'word',1,7,131)""" % s)  
conn.commit()

"""Закрываем соединение с БД"""  
curs.close()  
conn.close()
```

Что-то не получается добавить таким образом файл в БД. Правильно ли я добавляю файл - читаю в строку и добавляю за одну операцию INSERT в таблицу? Или надо читать файл построчно и в цикле записывать строки в базу данных??

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Ivan Babintsev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> cur.execute('''insert into test_blob values (%s, 'test from', 9)''',(open('test','rb').read(),))
>>> cur.commit()
```

Запись в таблице test_blob появилась.

Comment: Всем спасибо!

Вот мой вариант решения:

import sys  
import psycopg2  


HOST    = 'localhost'  
DB_NAME = 'gar'  
DB_USER = 'postgres'  
DB_PASS = ''  

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST,database=DB_NAME,user=DB_USER,password=DB_PASS)  
curs = conn.cursor()  

blob = psycopg2.Binary(open('report_29.py','rb').read())  

sql = """INSERT INTO "Reports_MCHS" VALUES (%s,'newreport', 1,'excel',0,6,170)"""  % blob  


curs.execute(sql)  
conn.commit()  

curs.close()  
conn.close()

Answer (score 1):

Скрипты я бы хранил в виде текста, думаю это разумнее, чем пихать файл в БД.

Comment: Согласен, но это у нас на работе есть такая система, которая хранит в БД файлы-скрипты, сохдающие разные отчеты. Если надо создать какой-нить отчет, она извлекает скрипт из БД, сохраняет его на диск и выполняет его запуск посредство вызова интерпретатора питон с передачей нужных параметров.

Comment: Т.е. она не может сохранить не файл на диск, а текст в файл на диск и выполнить его запуск? Пробовали `s=conn.binary(open('report_29.py','rb').read())` ?

Comment: похоже нет, не может. Такие нюансы я не знаю, как она выполняет эти отчеты. Знаю, что в вышеописанной таблице в поле "Script" bytea    
лежит содержимое файла-сценария на языке Python, который в результате своей работы создает отчет в виде OpenOffice документа(Word или Excel файл). Я хочу написать для себя скрипт, который бы мог помещать в эту таблицу написанный мною скрипт для генерации нового отчета.

Comment: я так понимаю это поле - "Script" bytea ' это BLOB поле.
То есть если перефразировать вопрос - как создать новую запись в таблице с BLOB  полем?